# BJT Transistor Biasing Problem

Tags: resistors, bjt, bias

If I have the circuit where I have Vcc = 30V and Vee = -30V. Transistor's beta equals 300. I want my Ic to be around 10mA and Vce = 25V, Vrc = 25V, Vre = 10V. I want to bias the base of transistor from the common node of both positive and negative supply rails, that is GND.

- What will be the voltage drop across Rb (base resistor)?

I have no idea how to calculate it in such situation...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYwh8zm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Did you do some calculations? could you share your calculations?

Comment: If you know Vre... knowing Vrb should be a no brainer....

Comment: Re = 10V/10mA = 1k ohm. Rc = 25V/10mA = 2.5k and Rb = (30V - 10V -0.7V) /(10mA/300) = 580k Ohm. So wher is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you want the voltage across \$R_E\$ to be \$10\:\textrm{V}\$ and you've specified your voltage rails. This means \$V_E=-20\:\textrm{V}\$, by definition. The only remaining question for you to ask yourself is "What is \$V_{BE}\$?" Because if you know that, you ***must*** then know the voltage across \$R_B\$. How can you not?

Seriously, this isn't so much a calculation as the fact that you've almost already specified the value, directly. \$\beta\$ doesn't even enter into the question, as it simply *does not matter*. You don't need to know the base current, as it simply *does not matter*. You've written the script and the answer is right there.

The only way to complicate this question would be to state, "Well, I don't know the value of \$V_{BE}\$ in this case." But that's probably not what you want to say.

Comment: 30 - Vre - Vbe = Vrb -> I get that. But 30 - Vrc - Vbc ≠ Vrb -> Can you explain that??

Comment: @Keno Where did you get Vbc?

Comment: Junction voltage - between collector and base, I measured it. According to KVL, the 30 - Vrc - Vbc should equal Vrb but it doesn't.

Comment: @Keno We are talking at cross-purposes, then, and not providing each other with enough information. I'm assuming you are talking about "in theory" and you bring in a specific measurement that is isolated from the rest of our discussion. So either we choose to discuss ACTUAL measurements you are making, and you fully disclose all of them, or else we stay on the theory side and instead help you to understand the measurements you are making. But we cannot mix our metaphores and get anywhere, I think. My answer was intended to address the idea of a paper problem I thought you presented.

Comment: @Keno In short, I can either help you understand a complete set of actual measurements, by applying theory to show you why they make sense; or else I can help you work out something from theory, and then explain measurements you make from there. But I cannot address myself to why one specific, actual measurement "here" doesn't add up to a list of theory-derived values "there." You have to keep apples with apples, so to speak.

Comment: Ah forget it, next time I will just make a voltage divider between two rails - positive and negative. I was just curious how the base can be biased from ground when used with two combined power supplies. That is all.

Comment: @Keno That's an odd question, now that you express it exactly that way. The answer is that you would not do that. The resistor divider technique allows you to set up ANY voltage you want (Thevenin) by just using two rails and the divider. Using ground with two other rails doesn't help because, once again, that means you are *stuck* with ground as your voltage. And you want the flexibility to select a voltage. Not the inflexibility of being stuck with just one, no matter which one it is. I think I see better where you were coming from, though. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't really understood what you meant with that last part of your comment but thank you anyway.

Comment: @Keno I'm sorry. It's hard to write a lot as a common. Until next time, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe if you draw this circuit this way will help you find the voltage across Rb resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fivOoU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There fore voltage drop across Rb = Ib*Rb = 10mA*580K/300

Comment: Not really, because I already knew that before. But thank you for trying.

Comment: 30 - Vre - Vbe = Vrb -> I get that. But 30 - Vrc - Vbc ≠ Vrb -> Can you explain that??

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think the problem here is that, due to the high resistance or Rb, the base voltage now is highly dependent on the transistor characteristics, which can vary greatly. In order to fulfill the requirement Vre=10V, you would want to have a fixed base potential of -19.3V. I would opt using a voltage divider to achieve this.